# Is it possible to call Azure Queue from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azureservicebus

My requirement is to send data received in Lambda from DynamoDB to Azure Queue in node.js.

Steps taken - AWS Side

```
   1. Created DDB Table
   2. Added Stream and Trigger
   3. Wrote Lambda
```

Steps taken - Azure Side

```
1. Created an Azure Queue (Service Bus)
```

So far so good. I can see DDB Events making its way to Lambda.

My question is now I want to send these events to Azure Queue, I could not find any online google result for this. Is it possible to put elements in Azure Queue from AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Service Bus REST API in order to send your messages:

```
POST    http{s}://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queuePath|topicPath}/messages
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue